# como fazer com que cada item do meu array ocupe um li diferente

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso fazer com que cada item do meu array saia em um li diferente, porem sempre que eu executo o codigo o meu array inteiro sai em apenas um li.

```js
// Crie o seguinte array: var deuses = ['Aegir', 'Aud', 'Balder', 'Bragi', 'Búri', 'Dag', 'Dellingr']
// E exiba todos os nomes, dentro do html: <ul></ul>
const lista = document.querySelector(".deuses");

const deuses = ["Aegir", "Aud", "Balder", "Bragi", "Búri", "Dag", "Dellingr"];

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  function criaLista() {
function criaLi() {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  return li;
}

function adicionaDeuses(array) {
  const li = criaLi();
  li.innerHTML = deuses;
  lista.appendChild(li);
}
adicionaDeuses(deuses);
  }
  criaLista();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<section class="area">
  <div class="lista">
    <ul class="deuses"></ul>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Algum motivo para ter criado uma função dentro de outra? Não me parece haver ganho nisso, pois apenas deixa o código mais confuso. Poderia ser bem mais simples, veja: https://jsfiddle.net/gv9o24yr/ - repare também que usei `textContent` em vez de `innerHTML`, pois neste caso você não tem um HTML, e sim apenas um texto simples em cada `li` (apesar do resultado ser o mesmo, há algumas diferenças importantes, pois `innerHTML` é um pouco mais "pesado", já que o seu valor precisa ser processado como um HTML, etc - [veja mais aqui](https://software.codidact.com/posts/284415/284420#answer-284420))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você tem uma lista de Deuses, você precisa criar várias li's e não somente uma como você está fazendo.

A ideia mais básica, seria iterar a lista de Deuses e ir criando uma `li` para cada.

Veja abaixo um exemplo bem simples, iterando a variável deuses com um `for of`:

```js
// Crie o seguinte array: var deuses = ['Aegir', 'Aud', 'Balder', 'Bragi', 'Búri', 'Dag', 'Dellingr']
// E exiba todos os nomes, dentro do html: <ul></ul>
const lista = document.querySelector(".deuses");

const deuses = ["Aegir", "Aud", "Balder", "Bragi", "Búri", "Dag", "Dellingr"];

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  function criaLista() {
    function criaLi() {
      const li = document.createElement("li");
      return li;
    }

    function adicionaDeuses(array) {
      for(const deus of deuses) {
        const li = criaLi();
        li.innerHTML = deus;
        lista.appendChild(li);
       }
    }
    adicionaDeuses(deuses);
  }
  criaLista();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="area">
      <div class="lista">
        <ul class="deuses"></ul>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

> Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of